# How to get output from PowerShell automation?

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am trying to get output and post output from PowerShell instance into textbox.  My code:

```
Private Sub ViewServiceLogToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ViewServiceLogToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Using ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
        Dim logFilePathName As String = "some path to log file"
        ps.AddScript(String.Format("get-content {0} -wait", logFilePathName))
        Dim outputCollection As PSDataCollection(Of PSObject) = New PSDataCollection(Of PSObject)
        AddHandler outputCollection.DataAdded, AddressOf LogFileOutput
        Dim result As IAsyncResult = ps.BeginInvoke(Of PSObject, PSObject)(Nothing, outputCollection)
    End Using
End Sub

Sub LogFileOutput(send As Object, data As DataAddedEventArgs)
    LogTextBox.Text += data.ToString
End Sub
```

I am unsure if this is running.  Placing break point inside LogFileOutput handler sub is never raised.  Thanks.

Comment: `AddCommand` expect command name, **only** command name.

Comment: ++ what @PetSerAl said. Use `AddScript()` if you want freeform statements

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have edited my work to use AddScript.  However, the real problem I am experiencing is outputting log file contents to TextBox.  (thanks)

Comment: @AdamCox Yes, I understand as much, but you need to actually write something to the file at `logFilePathName` for `Get-Content -Wait` to actually yield any output

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the file has contents.  If I open a powershell and execute the same command as is in my coded script, then the contents is output up to the end of the file and then it waits.  As I write more to file, more is output. I am looking for the same behavior in code.  (In review, I might be better to just go with async streamreader)

Comment: @AdamCox You should inspect `ps.Streams.Error` for errors.